# How can I populate a nested related collection with SailsJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have 3 collections,

`Users`,

`Clan`, which has many `Clanmembers`

`Clanmembers`, which has many `Users`

So when I do

`Clan.find().populate('clanmembers');`

It works fine and returns the result but then I get something like:

```
{ clanmembers:
   [ { role: 'Entry',
       owner: 2,
       member: 2,
       id: 1,
       createdAt: null,
       updatedAt: null } ],
  owner:
   { username: 'tester',
     email: 'tester',
     about: 'This is\n\na test hello\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhiiii',
     profileurl: '',
     avatar: 'asd.jpg',
     rank: '1',
     id: 2,
     createdAt: '2015-10-25T10:15:20.000Z',
     updatedAt: '2015-10-25T21:31:47.000Z' },
  clanname: 'testset',
  clantag: 'testin',
  id: 2,
  createdAt: '2015-10-26T01:07:02.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2015-10-26T01:07:02.000Z' }
```

What I'd like is also to be able to `populate` the `clanmembers` array's `owners` so that I can get usernames and what not of the clanmembers, how can I populate this nested array? Or is it not possible and I'll have to loop/find each one by their ID. Any information would be great thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done as of now, although it has been in the [talks](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/308) for quite some time.

As you mentioned, you'll have to do the population manually. But you can avoid making separate calls for each subdocument.

What I usually do is collect the required ids in an array and run a single query to the database, then maintain a map of ids to documents which makes it pretty convenient to use in multiple places.